# Unable to see hdfs file after loading to hive using spark sql

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a file from hdfs into hive using spark sql using below queries.

```
hiveContext.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (value STRING)")
hiveContext.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH '/data/spark_test/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src")
hiveContext.sql("FROM src SELECT *").collect().foreach(println)
```

What I find is,After the 2nd statement ie loading the file, I see the file in `/apps/hive/warehouse/src/` but it is not found in `/data/spark_test/kv1.txt` anymore. why is it so)?Spark version 1.6.1 used here.

Answer (score 1):

This is default behavior of hive, when you load data to table using `load data` command hive moves original source data to table location. 
You can find same file inside table location, run below commands to find source file.

```
describe extended src; --copy location
hadoop fs -ls <location>
```

As the `src` is external table so you may directly create external table on top of data instead of loading in next step.

```
hiveContext.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (value STRING) location '/data/spark_test'")
```